# Show that there exists no graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=6$ whose vertices have degrees $3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5$.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Show that there exists no graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=6$ whose vertices have degrees $3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5$.

At first I thought this problem would be very simple but I cant seem to crack it. I know Brook's theorem states that $\chi(G) \leq \Delta$ so that should be enough, but I think they want us to use a different argument for this. I tried a lot of tricks nothing seems to work. I'm sure there is a simple solution here but cant seem to get it.

Comment: Maybe Erdös-Gallai theorem could help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Gallai_theorem

Answer (score 1):

An easy idea is the following. We can give last $4$ vertices (of degree $5$) $4$ different colors. Then each of remaining vertices can be colored in one of $5$ colors (including these $4$ ones), because its degree is at most $4$, therefore adjacent vertices have at most $4$ different colors.